# What bill provided for public viewing of bills before Congressional vote?

Tags: united-states, congress, legislation

I cannot remember the name of this failed bill. I forget if it pertained to the House or the Senate or both.

The proposed legislation essentially stated that a bill would have to be viewed in its entirety before being voted on for some number of days.

So, the question is 'what is the name of the failed bill?'. I want to be able to look it up and reference it by name.

Comment: Do you have an approximate timeline for this?

Comment: @Joe I am thinking it was within the last 5 years.  I also think a North Carolina Congressperson was/is a proponent of it, although I don't remember which congressional rep it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was included in the 2010 Republican [Pledge to America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pledge_to_America) as "A requirement that Congress post all bills online three days before a vote."  But it wasn't a bill nor even a rule change.  It was just a promise about how they would do business.  They dropped it before the 2012 election.

This followed a 2009 proposal to make a rule, as reported by [Citizens Against Government Waste](https://www.cagw.org/thewastewatcher/72-hour-bill-struggle-read-over-shoulder-congress):

> Rep. Greg Walden (R-Ore.) filed a discharge petition to force a vote on H. Res. 554, a bipartisan-backed bill that would require all non-emergency legislation to be posted online in its final form 72 hours before a vote.

[H. Res. 554](https://www.congress.gov/bill/111th-congress/house-resolution/554).  In the Senate, it was [S. Res. 307](https://www.congress.gov/bill/111th-congress/senate-resolution/307) and [S. 1772](https://www.congress.gov/bill/111th-congress/senate-bill/1772).

Note:  this does not preclude there being other initiatives before or after these.  E.g. [H. Res. 330](https://www.congress.gov/bill/112th-congress/house-resolution/330) and [H. Res. 230](https://www.congress.gov/bill/112th-congress/house-resolution/230).